# why is my primary key editable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

why is my primary key field editable when my dynamic data scaffolds the fields for me. The primary key is set in the db properly. Using the Entity Framework. Any ideas?

using vs2008 pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you assume that a primary key should not be editable? How did you get to that conclusion?

To answer your question, any PK that is not auto-incremented is editable.

Comment: it is auto-incremented in the database

Comment: You need to use the ScaffoldColumnAttribute attribute to disable scaffolding mechanism for the identity column...

Comment: where do i find the field? what file?

Comment: According to MSDN "If the data field is automatically generated in the database, the data field is not displayed" so based on this your identity column should not be displayed at all...

Comment: "In order to apply the ScaffoldColumnAttribute attribute, you must create an associated metadata class where you will apply the ScaffoldColumnAttribute attribute to the data field and you must create a partial class that has the same name of the entity class in the data model. Then, you must associate these two classes by applying the MetadataTypeAttribute attribute to the partial class. "
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488540.aspx#Y1260